# Generalization with GRASS explodes number of polygons that are exported to GeoJSON

Tags: qgis, geojson, grass-gis, generalization

I have a shape file containing polygons with 10 geographical districts that together form a city, which I want to generalize without "sliver" artifacts and export to GeoJSON.

When running this vector layer through the built in "Simply" option in QGIS and exporting the simplified result to GeoJSON, I see one GeoJSON feature per district with polygon coordinates that represent each district. This is the output format I expect and know how to work with. However, the build in "Simplify" command is not topological aware and there are visual artifacts or "slivers" that are unwanted.

Example of acceptable output format from built-in "Simplify" command after export to GeoJSON (this will containing 10 features as expected):

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "District 1" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 38.724405, 8.998544 ], // ...
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "District 2" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 38.772469, 8.951595 ],  // ...
    // ...
  ]
}
```

For this reason I've turned to GRASS v.generalize that in QGIS generates a visually acceptable result without artifacts, but when exporting the generalization to geojson the number of polygons have exploded with multiple polygons being associated with the same district. I notice that the resulting geojson also contains properties "fid" and "cat" that is not present in the output from the simple generalization.

Example of output from GRASS v.generalize command after export to geojson (this will contain 677 features!):

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "fid": 1, "cat": 4, "name": "District 1" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 38.689519, 8.955512 ], // ...
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "fid": 2, "cat": 1, "name": "District 2" } "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 38.682155, 8.951824 ], // ...
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "fid": 3, "cat": 4, "name": "District 1" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 38.682155, 8.951824 ] // ...
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "fid": 4, "cat": 1, "name": "District 2"}, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 38.689519, 8.955512 ], // ...
    // ...
```

So, how do you make a topology aware generalization in QGIS (assumingly with GRASS v.generalize) that when exporting to GeoJSON does not create a lot of extra polygons polluting the end result, and keeping the number of polygons down to match what is actually seen on the screen?

Or alternatively how do you clean / merge the result to get the desired number of polygons (10 in this case)?